# Magento 2 - email template variable formatting

Tags: magento2, email-templates

I'm trying to format:

```
{{var order.getBaseTotalRefunded()}}
```

or

```
{{var creditmemo.grand_total}}
```

The output of both of these is:

```
261.6700
```

I read that the template editor allows Twig filters (https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/index.html), but I have tried a lot of them an none of them worked.

I'm trying to cut the number down to:

```
261.67
```

I have tried:

```
{{var order.getTotalRefunded() | number_format(2, '.', ',') }}
{{var order.getTotalRefunded()| format_number({fraction_digit: 2}) }}
{{var creditmemo.grand_total|raw|float|round: '2' }}
```

Any ideas how to get this to work correctly?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Found a workaround and just hardcoded this stuff into the PHTML template, but would be still nice to know since Magento documentation has 0 information on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try once

> {{var order.getTotalRefunded() | round: '2' }}

or if you are using custom email template use ,

```
Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface as priceHelper
$refundPrice = $priceHelper->convertAndFormat($order.getTotalRefunded())
```

and set the templeVar as  refundPrice